# ES6 React & ESLint Support

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

Writing a ES6 Flux/React app and wanting to use ESLint as well as Jest, however doesnt seem to be that much support/literature on the subject.

I realize I could transpile the ES6 code and run the Linting/Jesting on that codebase, but it wouldn't help me find the issue in the ES6 code. Is there any package out there that would accomplish what I'm trying to do, or is this something Facebook/React still needs to work out?

Comment: Coming back to this question - and it looks like there is now quite the support for ES6 in ESLint. I am using ESLint along with Mocha and I am able to debug code in ES6 gulp sourcemaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) for linting your code base and use [this plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest) for jest.
You will be able to run linting on your ES6 code but Jest will transpile before running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

To use ESLint with react, you can use https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react and activate `"jsx": true` in your .eslintrc
see an example in this project https://github.com/tddbin/tddbin-frontend/blob/master/.eslintrc#L5

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't include Jest, but I have an article about [writing React/Flux applications in ES6 using Babel and ESLint](https://medium.com/@tribou/react-and-flux-migrating-to-es6-with-babel-and-eslint-6390cf4fd878) which can hopefully provide some good examples.